# How to use cloudfront only on the internal network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am a junior developer studying aws.

I want to make cloudfront accessible only from my internal network.

However, when cloudfront is created, a distribution domain name is created and it seems that the domain is publicly accessible.

```
# current structure 
Route53(ACM) <-> Cloudfront <-> S3
```

I was wondering if there is a way to disable this.

Or, if there is a way to use cloudfront only on the internal network, please let me know.

I don't have much experience yet, so I need some help Please help!

Answer (score 3):

CloudFront is a content delivery network (CDN) service and as such, allows for the quick transfer of assets needed for **loading Internet content** including HTML pages, javascript files, stylesheets, images, and videos.

So CloudFront is designed for serve traffic globally. Is not possible to make it non publicly accesible.

You can add security using a Web Application Firewall and block some traffic according to rules but the endpoint still be public.